# Galera node not accepting root password after restart

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a Mariadb galera cluster running in Kubernetes with 2 Nodes.

Recently, as part of a process of redeploying the mariadb chart, one of them (`mariadb-1`), was restarted.

Trying to perform the following `mysql -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} -e 'SELECT 1';` results in this: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

The root password, as far as I can tell, was not changed as part of the redeployment process, and the other node (`mariadb-0`) still works fine, using the SAME password.

I did get 2 warnings during startup

```
2019-12-10 12:26:31 0 [Warning] WSREP: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
2019-12-10 12:26:32 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@mariadb-0' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
```

Any ideas on what might have caused this and how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a `root` user with host `localhost` in your `mysql.user` table? Are the other nodes running with the `--skip-name-resolve` option? Check with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_name_resolve';`.

Comment: in the problematic node, I can't tell unfortunately, because I can't login to it. In the other node, the mysql.user table is empty. and the skip_name_resolve variable is "ON"

Comment: Which version of MariaDB is this? Have you tried starting the problematic node with `skip_name_resolve=OFF`?